# Data Migration From a Sales Force Legacy system into a new system

Tags: data-migration

I have a client who's using a very old legacy system called **Sales Cloud Contact Manager** and he is looking to migrate his existing data from that legacy system into **Salesforce essential/Professional**.

We have contacted the sales force regarding this, and they advised that we need to work with one of their partners since this migration is not an easy and straightforward process.

we have received a $ +2000 quote from one of their partners regarding this migration task that in my opinion is expensive for a task that may not be too complex.

So I'm trying to figure out the following to see if we need to work with a 3rd party company or if it's something we can do ourselves.

1. What are the steps for this migration? Is it very complex time-consuming?
2. what tools are required? Is there a tool that we can use to export the data from the legacy system and import it onto the new system?
3. Is this something we can do on our own or is it more complex than we are anticipating
4. Which version of Salesforce should we choose? essential or Professional. The essential has all the features we need. However, we have been told if we need to migrate our existing data, we need the professional version. is that correct?

Any help or tips would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> What are the steps for this migration? Is it very complex time-consuming?

There are only three steps, what we call ETL, or Extract-Transform-Load. It is technically a simple process, but it may be very involved time-wise, if you have a lot of objects to load.

> what tools are required? Is there a tool that we can use to export the data from the legacy system and import it onto the new system?

You can export data just by running reports. Nose that this limited edition has no API access, so virtually no tools exist for exporting. You might also have a data export option in Setup | Data Export. This is a limited use feature, so make sure you select everything you need. If it's not there, Support should be able to enable it for a one-time use.

Importing into Essentials will be limited to Accounts and Contacts. With Professional Edition, you should be able to access at least the Excel Connector for easier importing. You can also get API access on Professional Edition for importing using Data Loader or another ETL app.

> Is this something we can do on our own or is it more complex than we are anticipating

That depends on the number of objects and records involved. If you just want Accounts and Contacts, that's easy. If you want Accounts, Contacts, Call History, Emails, Calendar Events, etc, it will be dramatically more complicated to keep everything straight.

> Which version of Salesforce should we choose? essential or Professional. The essential has all the features we need. However, we have been told if we need to migrate our existing data, we need the professional version. is that correct?

Essentials had virtually no data import, as it has no API access. If you want to migrate, you'll need at least Professional Edition. Also, you'll likely find that Professional is probably worth the upgrade (personally, I'd go with Enterprise Edition, but I do realize it's expensive).